# How to get this done using Hibernate or SQL?

Tags: sql, hibernate

I'm working on a software where the Time Table of a school is related. The following is the scenario.

A class( say 12M1 ) has a list of subjects. A class belongs to a section (say Math section) and a section also has a set of subjects. In all the classes in the section,  the section's subjects are taught as well. A section belongs to a grade ( say grade 12 ) and a grade also has subjects. In all the classes in a section, the section's grade's subjects are taught as well.

What I need to get done is to get a list of subjects taught in each class.

I can see that this can be done using multiple queries and iteration.
For example

- for each class first get its list of subjects.
- Then from    its section get the subjects and add to the list.
- Then form its    section's grade get the subjects and add to the list.

Is there a better/cleaner way of doing this?
For example using a single query?
Using hibernate or SQL?

Answer (score 1):

all subjects of a class

```
DetachedCritiera subjects = DetachedCritiera.for(Class.class)
    .add(Expression.eq("id", classId))
    .createAlias("subjects", "subject")
    .setProjection(Projections.Property("subject.Id"));

DetachedCritiera sectrionSubjects = DetachedCritiera.for(Class.class)
    .add(Expression.eq("id", classId))
    .createAlias("section", "section")
    .createAlias("section.subjects", "subject")
    .setProjection(Projections.Property("subject.Id"));

DetachedCritiera gradeSubjects = DetachedCritiera.for(Class.class)
    .add(Expression.eq("id", classId))
    .createAlias("grade", "grade")
    .createAlias("grade.subjects", "subject")
    .setProjection(Projections.Property("subject.Id"));

List<Subject> allSubjectsOfClass = session.createCriteria(Subject.class)
    .add(new Disjunction()
        .add(Subqueries.in("id", subjects))
        .add(Subqueries.in("id", sectrionSubjects))
        .add(Subqueries.in("id", gradeSubjects))
    )
    .list<Subject>();
```